# Unable to validate query output in MySQL with window_functions

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote a query to solve a problem but I am not able to validate it as its pseudo code-focused. I hope someone can look over this query and tell me if I am missing anything. Thank you in advance.

**Problem:**
 
Find all users who bought from the same retailer at least in three distinct weeks within 1 month and who spent purchase amounts which are within 5% of each other.

My Query:

```
select distinct a.customer_id, a.purchase_date 

from 
(
select 
  customer_id,
  retailer,
  purchase_date,
  WEEK(purchase_date)as wk,
  purchase_amount,
  Lag(purchase_amount) over (partition by customer_id,retailer) as previous_amt,
  Lag(WEEK(purchase_date)) over (partition by customer_id,retailer) as previous_wk,
  count(WEEK(purchase_date)) over (partition by customer_id,retailer)count
  from tbl
)a 

where (a.wk-a.previous_wk)<(1/7)*30 
and a.count>2
and abs(a.purchase_amount-a.previous_amt)/a.purchase_amount <=0.05
```

Please let me know if you see any issue with this query. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I take 'month' to mean calendar month in this instance, but I don't think you agree?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thats the issue. i dont have sample data. it was an abstract question. Are you still able to help?